# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: "<_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:/Users/muham/OneDrive/Desktop/test' mode='w' encoding='cp1252'>.csv"

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, csv, tkinter

```
    def exportproductsdata():
    ff = filedialog.asksaveasfile()
    gg = producttable.get_children()
    id, barcode, product_name, p_type, purchased_from, made_by, mmodel, p_price, r_price,decs,addeddate,updateddate = [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [],[],[],[]
    for i in gg:
        content = producttable.item(i)
        pp = content['values']
        id.append(pp[0]),\
        barcode.append(pp[1]),\
        product_name.append(pp[2]),\
        p_type.append(pp[3]),\
        purchased_from.append(pp[4]),\
        made_by.append(pp[5]), \
        mmodel.append(pp[6]), \
        p_price.append(pp[7]), \
        r_price.append(pp[8]),\
        decs.append(pp[9]),\
        addeddate.append(pp[10]),\
        updateddate.append(pp[11])

    dd = ['Product Id ', 'Product Barcode','Product Name', 'Product Type', 'Purchased From ', 'Made By', 'Model ', 'Purchase Price', 'Retail Price', 'Description','Added Date','Updated Date']
    df = pandas.DataFrame(list(zip(id, barcode, product_name, p_type, purchased_from, made_by, mmodel, p_price, r_price,decs,addeddate,updateddate)),columns=dd)

    paths = '{}.csv'.format(ff)

    df.to_csv(paths,mode='w', encoding=None, index=False)

    messagebox.showinfo("notification", "data exported successfully {}".format(path))
```

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\muham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 1883, in **call**
return self.func(*args)
File "C:/Users/muham/PycharmProjects/JapanMedicalComapny/venv/Scripts/admin.py", line 172, in exportproductsdata
df.to_csv(paths,mode='w', encoding=None, index=False)
File "C:\Users\muham\PycharmProjects\JapanMedicalComapny\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3167, in to_csv
formatter.save()
File "C:\Users\muham\PycharmProjects\JapanMedicalComapny\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py", line 185, in save
f, handles = get_handle(
File "C:\Users\muham\PycharmProjects\JapanMedicalComapny\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 493, in get_handle
f = open(path_or_buf, mode, encoding=encoding, errors=errors, newline="")
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: "<_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:/Users/muham/OneDrive/Desktop/test' mode='w' encoding='cp1252'>.csv"

Comment: Look in the error message "name='C:/Users/muham/OneDrive/Desktop/test' mode='w' encoding='cp1252'>.csv"". It is not clear why from the provided code unless it is a bug in the to_csv() method.

Comment: thank you so much... (ShayneLoyd)